# Bootstrap 3 columns not touching even though @grid-gutter-width is 0

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 with my project to make a high school assignments organizer. The two columns for the weekends are supposed to be half the width of the normal, week day columns and the rows are supposed to have double height, like in this image:

[image: What's supposed to happen]

My solution was to put the content with the normal columns within `<div class="col-md-10">`and the other two columns in a `div class="col-md-2"`, like in [this example](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/offcanvas/#).

The problem is that at the end of each row of the normal columns, the row is taking up an extra 60 or so pixels (even though the @grid-gutter-width variable in the LESS source is set to 0, and all sub-columns within each top-level column touch with no gutter-width as they are supposed to), so the col-md-10 and the col-md-2 are not touching. Looking in the inspector in Chrome. It just shows that the rows have extra length, as if another element was on the end of each row, even though nothing is there. This is how the page actually looks:

[image: What actually happens]

Notice the gap that I mentioned earlier. Is there any way this can be fixed?

Comment: Sorry about that! [here's the source on Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/qbQqQbWg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you count the `col-md-*`'s in the `col-md-10` they only add up to 11, they need to add up to 12 to join up with the content of `col-md-2`.

I changed the subject to be a `col-md-2` rather than a `col-md-1` and it joined up[image]